# Matplotlib: Same title for 8 plots plotted using loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code which generates 8 plots. I want to put the phases as titles in each plot. So I have succeded to put the phase on the plot. But instead of taking corresponding phase, it is always taking the last phase to show in each plot. The 8phases.txt file has the following 8 lines which I want to put in each plot -

```
-1   1   -1    
-1   1    1
 1   1    1
 1  -1    1
-1  -1   -1
 1   1   -1
 1  -1   -1
-1  -1    1
```

Here is the code -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

D=12
n=np.arange(1,4)
x = np.linspace(-D/2,D/2, 3000)
I = np.array([125,300,75])
phase = np.genfromtxt('8phases.txt')
I_phase = I*phase

for i in I_phase:
    F = sum(m*np.cos(2*np.pi*l*x/D) for m,l in zip(i,n))
    f,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
    for row in phase:
        ax1.plot(x,F,'g')
        ax1.set_title(row)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I believe you are using `plt.subplots` incorrectly, though I'm not extremely experiences with this.  Hopefully someone more experienced will be able to point out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your inner-most loop is unnecessary; it is recreating the same plot 8 times and updating the title 8 times with each of the 8 values.

If I understood what you are asking for, I believe this gives the correct results:

```
...

for index,i in enumerate(I_phase):
    F = sum(m*np.cos(2*np.pi*l*x/D) for m,l in zip(i,n))
    f,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
    ax1.plot(x,F,'g')
    ax1.set_title(phase[index])

...
```

(I would normally use "i" instead of "index", but you had already used "i")